# Ubuntu loads then black screen of death

Tags: boot, hdmi, bios

So originally i was trying to enable usb3 on my workstation. How I got to where I am is a story. I screwed up some bios setting and My computer wouldnt boot. Then I replaced the CMOS battery on the mother board, And now it is close to working. but not quite. (its actually way far off ). So now that I reset the BIOS settings, I hear the intel server board's 2 beeps (which means recovery mode), Still no hdmi signal. Then i wait 2 minutes, The screen shows an ubuntu loading image. It skips from dot one, to dot two , then to 5 (this didnt happen before). And then, my monitor tells me that 'there is no hdmi signal'. Right there I notice 2 fishy things. When the board beeped twice, bios should have popped up on the screen (which it did not). Also, ubuntu fails to show itself (the login). i dont know how to procede. It may help to tell you, that I had to remove the graphics card to access the CMOS Battery slot. Maybe I screwed it up and the hdmi fails to travel to the monitor. Is it possible to boot without a graphics card? Anyway, my question is *How do I get from here to BIOS or some interface that actually interacts with me so that I can try to fix this*? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should start by reseting BIOS to default. From there make the appropriate changes if needed.

Comment: I already reset BIOS by replacing the CMOS battery

Comment: Not necessarily. Please open BIOS settings and select the option to reset to default or optimal settings. Work *from* there.

Comment: but then again, BIOS doesnt show up on my monitor

Comment: I am starting to think that this is legitimatly a graphics card problem

Comment: If so, we cannot help, it's off topic. But try booting a live USB to see how it goes.